# npm install for react-navigation-drawer not working

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

Following is the error on the terminal after running the command.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\react-native\reviewsApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer
npm ERR! dest C:\react-native\reviewsApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\.drawer.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\react-native\reviewsApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer' -> 'C:\react-native\reviewsApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\.drawer.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\saumya bhatnagar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-28T20_44_21_098Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting node_module and try "npm install"